# Use search kit like a pivot table?

Tags: searchkit

Ive used search kit and created a list of service user demographics, there are 7 columns, age, gender, ethnicity etc.

I then download the csv, copy and paste to excel and then have to create pivot for the different headings.

Is there any way that this can be done in search kit at all?

Answer (score 2):

You could script it as an excel macro but yes in 5.50 there will be something similar called Segmentation in search kit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-0 I have no idea what the first bit means - my excel skills are good but not that good. :-) . I am leaving my job soon so wont be in a position to do it, but thanks for the segmentation tip